# Can't update user profile in my Django app Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, profile

I have created a Edit Profile form in my Django app but it doesn't save in the database.

This is the profile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True) #Each User is related to only one User Profile
    city_search_text = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)#user picks a city from autocomplete and in the view I get or create a City object
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True, related_name='city') #Each User Profile must be related to one city.
    prof_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pictures')
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

This is the form:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('dob',)#I'm testing to update this field only

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile
```

This is the view:

```
def editprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edit_profile_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if edit_profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = edit_profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()

            if 'next' in request.GET:
                return redirect(request.GET['next'])
        else:
            print (profile_form.errors)
    else:
        edit_profile_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request, 'excurj/editprofile.html', {'edit_profile_form':edit_profile_form,})
```

After I submit the form it forwards me to index page okay but the values remain the same in the user's profile.

Comment: Your overridden `save` method does nothing useful at all; you should remove it. And you don't need to do `commit=False` in the view either; just save it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

```
if edit_profile_form.is_valid():
```

isn't getting called at all, and your data is not saved. That means your form has invalid data, and you should check for form errors to detect those.

Also, you are trying to print form errors if the request isn't POST, which makes no sense and won't help you printing form errors. Try using this way;

```
if edit_profile_form.is_valid():
    profile = edit_profile_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.save()
else:
    print (profile_form.errors)
```

And check your form for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually. In the view I should have passed an instance of the profile not the User object. So it needs to be like this:

```
edit_profile_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.*profile*)
```